# Trouble with assigning new values to the elements of an iterator using for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, iterator, iteration, variable-assignment

i have a problem with assigning new values to the elements of an iterator using for loop. let's say we have this list:

```html
some_2d_list = [['mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean'],
 ['world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python']]
```

why does this code work and change the elements of the original list(reversing the elements which themselves are lists):

```html
for items in some_2d_list:
        items = items.reverse()
```

but this one does not(we will have to use indexes to apply changes in this case):

```html
for items in some_2d_list:
        items = ["some new list"]
```

I was expecting this result with the latter code:

```html
some_2d_list = [["some new list"],
 ["some new list"]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.reverse` reverses in-place and returns None, so

```
for items in some_2d_list:
    items = items.reverse()
```

reverses the existing list which is still in `some_2d_list` and assigns `None` to `items`.

When you enter the code block in `for items in some_2d_list`, `items` is a reference to the object still in `some_2d_list`. Anything that modifies the existing list, affects `some_2d_list` also. for example

```
>>> some_2d_list = [['mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean'],
...  ['world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python']]
>>> 
>>> for items in some_2d_list:
...     items.append('foo')
...     del items[1]
... 
>>> some_2d_list
[['mean', 'is', 'jean', 'foo'], ['world', 'rocks', 'python', 'foo']]
```

Augmented operations like "+=" are ambiguous. Depending on how any given type is implemented, it can update in place or create new objects. They work for lists

```
>>> some_2d_list = [['mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean'],
...  ['world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python']]
>>> 
>>> for items in some_2d_list:
...     items += ['bar']
... 
>>> some_2d_list
[['mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean', 'bar'], ['world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python', 'bar']]
```

but not for tuples

```
>>> some_2d_list = [('mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean'), ('world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python')]
>>> for items in some_2d_list:
...     items += ('baz',)
... 
>>> some_2d_list
[('mean', 'really', 'is', 'jean'), ('world', 'my', 'rocks', 'python')]
```

Comment: So we use any other in-place methods over the items and it will work?

Comment: weird that item+="foo" works for lists but item = item +"foo" does not!

Comment: @Sherafati - its kinda random. The `list` implementers use the `extend` method for "+=" and extend works on iterators. So, even `l += range(10)` works. Its not symmetric with "+" , which argues against doing it that way but it is rather esthetically pleasing.